# Cut string from one point to another point in PHP

Tags: php, string, substr

I want to make script that his action is to cut string from one point to another point.

for example:

```
<div id="box" style="font-size:bold;height:30px;width:100px;border: 1px solid black">xx</div>
```

i want that the script will cut all the style., and it will be something like:

```
<div id="box">xx </div>
```

how can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is replace the style attribute you can do this:

```
$str = '<div id="box" style="font-size:bold;height:30px;width:100px;border: 1px solid black">xx</div>';
$str = preg_replace('/ style=\"[^\"]*\"/', '', $str);
```

Comment: if i want to take the id or the class and save it on array and then to take the inline style of the current id or class and save it in another array, how can i do it ? thanks,